# TFS 2010 B2 64-bit build agent "unknown state"

Tags: tfs, build, agent, 64-bit

Our TF Server is installed on a Windows 2008 Server (32-bit) and the build service is installed on a 2008 Server 64-bit. When attempting to get the build service going, the agent is reported as being in an unknown state. When testing connections between the controller and agent, everything is fine but it is impossible to successfully build. The last step the build gets to is "Run on Agent" and then aborts.

We have an older build box that has the 32-bit TFS build service installed and that agent runs fine. Its status shows up as ready and the automated build works like a charm.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is actually no longer an issue since the RC was installed on both servers. Everything is working as expected.